# How to show minimal surface equation is a non-uniform elliptic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

The minimal surface equation is 
$$
\sum D_i \left(\frac{D_i u }{\sqrt{1+ |Du|^2}}\right)=0
$$
How to show it is a non-uniform elliptic equation ?

What I try:
$$
D_i \left(\frac{D_i u }{\sqrt{1+ |Du|^2}}\right)
=
\frac{D_{ii}u}{\sqrt{1+ |Du|^2}}
-\frac{D_iu \sum D_juD_{ij}u}{2(1+ |Du|^2)^{3/2}}
$$
so the coefficient of $D_{ii}u$ is 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ |Du|^2}}
-\frac{(D_iu)^2 }{2(1+ |Du|^2)^{3/2}}
$$
the coefficient of $D_{ij}u$ is 
$$
\frac{D_iu  D_ju}{2(1+ |Du|^2)^{3/2}}
$$
then, how to get the minimum eigenvalue and maximal  eigenvalue of the coefficient matrix ? In my read book, it says the ratio of minimum eigenvalue and maximal  eigenvalue is $1+ |Du|^2$. But I can't calculate it.

Comment: I think you are missing a factor 2 coming from the derivative of $|Du|^2$.

Comment: And probably also a minus. Anyway, once you have the right coefficient matrix $(a_{ij})$, you should evaluate it on a vector (i.e. look at $\sum_{ij} a_{ij} v_i v_j$) and compare it with $|v|^2$.